# Change user agent in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, http, registry, user-agent

I'm looking for a unified solution for changing IE's user agent completely (the way it does through dev tools on ie 11) for versions 7 and higher, or at least deleting the trident tokens, we are not allowed to use any add-ons for this, so only programmatic\files\registry changes allowed, registry can not solve this problem though, any ideas of implementing such thing  would be nice, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to force the browser in compatibility mode through the X-UA-Compatible Meta Tag?
See these sites for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd835379.aspx
http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm

Comment: In such case, you can use the Group Policy mechanism of Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321457.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/10/23/how-to-add-web-site-to-compatibility-view-list-via-gpo.aspx

Comment: and again, it is all about some "local" changes, I want it to be like one setting to affect useragent for each website